# Python multiprocessing: synchronizing file-like object

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-2.6, python-multithreading

I'm trying to make a file like object which is meant to be assigned to sys.stdout/sys.stderr during testing to provide deterministic output. It's not meant to be fast, just reliable. What I have so far *almost* works, but I need some help getting rid of the last few edge-case errors.

Here is my current implementation.

```
try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from StringIO import StringIO

from os import getpid
class MultiProcessFile(object):
    """
    helper for testing multiprocessing

    multiprocessing poses a problem for doctests, since the strategy
    of replacing sys.stdout/stderr with file-like objects then
    inspecting the results won't work: the child processes will
    write to the objects, but the data will not be reflected
    in the parent doctest-ing process.

    The solution is to create file-like objects which will interact with
    multiprocessing in a more desirable way.

    All processes can write to this object, but only the creator can read.
    This allows the testing system to see a unified picture of I/O.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        # per advice at:
        #    http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#all-platforms
        from multiprocessing import Queue
        self.__master = getpid()
        self.__queue = Queue()
        self.__buffer = StringIO()
        self.softspace = 0

    def buffer(self):
        if getpid() != self.__master:
            return

        from Queue import Empty
        from collections import defaultdict
        cache = defaultdict(str)
        while True:
            try:
                pid, data = self.__queue.get_nowait()
            except Empty:
                break
            cache[pid] += data
        for pid in sorted(cache):
            self.__buffer.write( '%s wrote: %r\n' % (pid, cache[pid]) )
    def write(self, data):
        self.__queue.put((getpid(), data))
    def __iter__(self):
        "getattr doesn't work for iter()"
        self.buffer()
        return self.__buffer
    def getvalue(self):
        self.buffer()
        return self.__buffer.getvalue()
    def flush(self):
        "meaningless"
        pass
```

... and a quick test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6

from multiprocessing import Process
from mpfile import MultiProcessFile

def printer(msg):
    print msg

processes = []
for i in range(20):
    processes.append( Process(target=printer, args=(i,), name='printer') )

print 'START'
import sys
buffer = MultiProcessFile()
sys.stdout = buffer

for p in processes:
    p.start()
for p in processes:
    p.join()

for i in range(20):
    print i,
print

sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
print 
print 'DONE'
print
buffer.buffer()
print buffer.getvalue()
```

This works perfectly 95% of the time, but it has three edge-case problems. I have to run the test script in a fast while-loop to reproduce these.

1. 3% of the time, the parent process output isn't completely reflected. I assume this is because the data is being consumed before the Queue-flushing thread can catch up. I haven't though of a way to wait for the thread without deadlocking.
2. .5% of the time, there's a traceback from the multiprocess.Queue implementation
3. .01% of the time, the PIDs wrap around, and so sorting by PID gives the wrong ordering.

In the very worst case (odds: one in 70 million), the output would look like this:

```
START

DONE

302 wrote: '19\n'
32731 wrote: '0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 '
32732 wrote: '0\n'
32734 wrote: '1\n'
32735 wrote: '2\n'
32736 wrote: '3\n'
32737 wrote: '4\n'
32738 wrote: '5\n'
32743 wrote: '6\n'
32744 wrote: '7\n'
32745 wrote: '8\n'
32749 wrote: '9\n'
32751 wrote: '10\n'
32752 wrote: '11\n'
32753 wrote: '12\n'
32754 wrote: '13\n'
32756 wrote: '14\n'
32757 wrote: '15\n'
32759 wrote: '16\n'
32760 wrote: '17\n'
32761 wrote: '18\n'

Exception in thread QueueFeederThread (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 233, in _feed
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

In python2.7 the exception is slightly different:

```
Exception in thread QueueFeederThread (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 268, in _feed
<type 'exceptions.IOError'>: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

How do I get rid of these edge cases?

Comment: What's the actual question you're asking?  Why you're getting those exceptions?  Why each of the edge cases are happening?

Comment: @Daniel: How to get rid of those three problems. I think I've made myself more clear by adding a sentence to the introduction. Does that help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution came in two parts. I've successfully run the test program 200 thousand times without any change in output.

The easy part was to use multiprocessing.current_process()._identity to sort the messages. This is not a part of the published API, but it is a unique, deterministic identifier of each process. This fixed the problem with PIDs wrapping around and giving a bad ordering of output.

The other part of the solution was to use multiprocessing.Manager().Queue() rather than the multiprocessing.Queue. This fixes problem #2 above because the manager lives in a separate Process, and so avoids some of the bad special cases when using a Queue from the owning process. #3 is fixed because the Queue is fully exhausted and the feeder thread dies naturally before python starts shutting down and closes stdin.

Comment: multiprocessing.Manager().Queue() rather than the multiprocessing.Queue got rid of the "<type 'exceptions.IOError'>: [Errno 32] Broken pipe" error in python 2.7 for me

Comment: @JoshuaRichardson Using a `multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()` solves it for me, too. But my tests take about 7 times as long as with the `mutliprocessing.queues.Queue()`.

Comment: @Bengt: I hope you're not making one manager for each queue. You just need one. Could you show us a minimal benchmark?

Comment: @JoshuaRichardson I think it is better to use new manager objects each time in tests, because that eliminates the possibility of side effects, making the cause more obvious when tests fail. For me the costs are acceptable, but others may find it to be very costly depending on the the proportion of queue instantiations versus other code.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered far fewer `multiprocessing` bugs with Python 2.7 than with Python 2.6. Having said this, the solution I used to avoid the "`Exception in thread QueueFeederThread`" problem is to `sleep` momentarily, possibly for 0.01s, in each process in which the the `Queue` is used. It is true that using `sleep` is not desirable or even reliable, but the specified duration was observed to work sufficiently well in practice for me. You can also try 0.1s.

Comment: Narcolepsy is never a reliable solution.