# Python3: Threadsafe mechanisms to redirect stdin, stdout, stderr

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, io, synchronization

I'm attempting to redirect stdin, stdout, and stderr of a debugged program in python, and quickly saw that other people have had success by assigning [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) instances to sys.stdin/out/err.

However, the debugged program is in one thread, while the StringIO instances are being written to and read from using a different thread. No documentation that I can find describes StringIO objects as being thread safe, and while I can wrap my own read/write calls in locks, I don't think I can force the debugged programs to use those same locks.

How can I force StringIO to do what I want? Otherwise, what will do what I want?

**Edit:**
As requested an example of an anticipated race condition is as follows:

let's say I'm reading from stdout. I read the StringIO's full contents, and then flush the object... except that between my read and flush operations, the debugged program has printed more information, which also ends up getting flushed. In other words, I'm losing some of the information.

**Edit 2:**
I found another question essentially asking [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821880/python-multiprocessing-synchronizing-file-like-object), but his answer doesn't seem very pythonic, so I'm leaving this open

Comment: sorry if this is unclear to only me, but what sort of thread-unsafe behavior are you worried about? is there a specific race you're trying to prevent?

Comment: I've put in a quick edit to illustrate what I mean

Comment: use a queue, put the message to write in from thread1, while loop in thread2 with `try: queue.get(timeout=0.1) except queue.Empty: pass` .

Comment: @T4rk1n No, I'm debugging a script whose content I have no control over. I have to work with stdin, stdout, and stderr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the answer while skimming through [Qdb](https://code.google.com/archive/p/rad2py/wikis/QdbRemotePythonDebugger.wiki)'s source code. This implementation reassigns **stdin**, **stdout**, and **stderr** to `self`, and implements the following file-like functions:

```
close
encoding
isatty
flush
writelines
write
readlines
readline
```

Now, because all of the io functions are within your class (assuming you're using a class), you can control synchronization all day long.